# Twitter Bootstrap set height of content area to maximum (no scrollbar)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a basic Twitter Bootstrap Layout where I want to set the content area to maximum that no scrollbar appears.

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 well">Head</div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 well">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 well" style="height: 100% !important">
          <div role="tabpanel">
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
              <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content">
              <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                <div class="well">Home Area</div>
              </div>
              <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
                <div class="well">Profile Area</div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 well"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

I have create a plunk with tabs in the main area, the content of each tab should use the maximum available height.

http://plnkr.co/edit/wp6qv9J4pKY4ROdo74bF

Comment: Perhaps you should alter your example so that it shows scroll bars, that way we have a better idea of the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I have updated the plunk, but the height of the tab-pane is not at max.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is possible. You can set the height of a well using pixels but not percentages. As such you may need to write a bit of JavaScript/jQuery to dynamically set the height of these tab content wells. For that matter, I'm not sure why you want to contain all of the tab content in a well to begin with. Looks odd and isn't really meant for that.